# cygwin perl subroutine executing out of order

Tags: perl, subroutine

I wrote this simple program with a subroutine. 
It acts strangely when I put it in a sub routine.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w 
use strict ; 
sub get_name {
    print "what is your name ?\n" ;
    my $name = <STDIN> ;
    chomp($name) ;
    print "Hello $name\n";
  }

get_name ;
```

This is the result

```
$ ./name_print
casper
what is your name ?
Hello casper
```

It never prints the what is your name string. 
It waits for me to enter in some standard input , and then prints the "what is your name string". It executes out of order. 
Very strange.

Comment: I can't reproduce your behavior. On my system it prints the question 1st.

Comment: Its working for me. It prints question first and after that when I enter a name it prints hello message with name.

Comment: What shell are you running this in?  Does using \r\n instead of \n make a difference?

Answer (score 2):

This type of behaviour can be created if perl is confused about what type of buffering it should do to the IO.  Try adding the following line.

```
$|++;
```

Just after your 'use strict;' to force perl to flush the buffers after every print statement.